# How to duplicate a text in real time with plain JS

Tags: javascript

What I need is to copy what I type from one form to another in real time using only plain JS. Here's what I have at the moment, not sure why it doesn't work and if it's possible at all:

```js
const textField = document.getElementById('text');

function change() {
  let src = document.getElementById("text");
  let dest = document.getElementById("duplicateField");
  dest.value = src.value;
}

textField.addEventListener("keyup", change);
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <label>
        Текст
        <input id="text" type="text" placeholder="Enter your text">
    </label>
</form>
<hr>
<input type="text" id="duplicateField" placeholder="Your text">
```

Comment: Works here... Not sure what you're seeing.

Comment: add the following or explain what does not work the only thing i could find was that it didn't spam keys if you hold a key
`textField.addEventListener("keypress", change);
textField.addEventListener("keydown", change);`

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> [mcve] -> _"**"It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem.** Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question."_

Comment: It seems like something happened to my IDE as it works anywhere apart from it. Pardon me for not checking it elsewhere initially

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="#">
<label>
    Текст
    <input id="text" type="text" placeholder="Enter your text">
</label>
</form>
<hr>
<input type="text" id="duplicateField" placeholder="Your text">


<script>
    const input = document.getElementById("text");
    const duplicateField = document.getElementById("duplicateField");

    input.addEventListener('keyup',() => {
        duplicateField.value = input.value;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add keyup listener to src element.

```js
let src = document.getElementById("text");
src.addEventListener('keyup', change, false);
function change(e) {
  document.getElementById("duplicateField").setAttribute('value', e.target.value);
}
```

```html
<body>
<form action="#">
    <label>
        Текст
        <input id="text" type="text" placeholder="Enter your text">
    </label>
</form>
<hr>
<input type="text" id="duplicateField" placeholder="Your text" >
<p id="duplicateField"></p>
</body>
```

Check this example

Comment: doesn't work, change event is only fired when you unfocus the input box

Comment: A code-only dump is not helpful for OP nor future readers.

Comment: Also OPs script works as you can see in the question, so why does this require an answer?

Comment: "When you are done adding text to src element". The OP said real time